# How to resolve below Dataloader error

Tags: data-loader, error, exception, data

Too many retries of batch save in the presence of Apex triggers with failures: when triggers are present partial save requires that some subset of rows save without any errors in order to avoid inconsistent side effects from those triggers. Number of retries: 2

Answer (score 0):

If you ever run into this error; turn on the logs, identify the trigger and straight go to your trigger and review the code.

Most likely there is a bulk DML operation happening in the trigger which has AllorNone option set to True.

Review the following Salesforce document which explains in details the process:-

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.enus.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_bulk_exceptions.htm

Review the data is being loaded and try to load with smaller sets and see if the problem is locatable.

Fix the problem and then load in bulk.

Reference:- http://dbalur.blogspot.com/2016/05/